# Using LINQ, how do I get rows M through M+N?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm creating a paging system for my view, whereby the top 20 items (or fewer if there are less than 20 total) ordered by a column's value show on the view, then a viewer can click "Page 2" to see items 21 through 40 (or fewer if there are less than 40 in total), then "Page 3" to see items 41-60, etc. My controller has a member

```
private static const int _scoresPerPage = 20;
```

and I'm constructing a method

```
    public string getPageNRows ( int N )
    {
         string scoresRowsHtml = String.Empty; 
         // ... 
         return scoresRowsHtml;  
    }
```

which retrives the information. Now, I know how to get `0` through `ScoresController._scoresPerPage * N`, so that I could technically do something like

```
    public string getPageNRows ( int N )
    {
        string scoresRowsHtml = String.Empty;
        IQueryable<Score> table1 = ( from s in this._SD.Scores
                                            orderby s.score1 descending
                                            select s
                                           ).Take(ScoresController._scoresPerPage * N);
        IQueryable<Score> table2 = ( from s in table1 
                                     orderby s.score1 ascending
                                     select s).Take(ScoresController._scoresPerPage);
        table2.Reverse(); 
        // ... 
        return scoresRowsHtml;
    }
```

but obviously that is ridiculous. What should I really be doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to combine [Skip()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358985(v=vs.100).aspx) with Take()

```
IQueryable<Score> table1 = ( from s in this._SD.Scores
                             orderby s.score1 descending
                             select s
                             ).Skip(ScoresController._scoresPerPage * (N-1))
                             ).Take(ScoresController._scoresPerPage);
```

Assuming N == 1 means the first page.